# Valuation in definition of Weil Divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I'm studyng divisors from *Basic Algebraic Geometry* of Shafarevich. He takes an irreducible quasi-projective variety $X$, regular in codimension $1$ and claims that for any codimension-one irreducible subvariety  $C\subset X$ there exists an affine open $U\subset X$ such that $C\cap U$ is defined by the local equation $\pi\in k[U]$. If I have correctly understood, this means that the prime ideal of regular functions on $U$ vanishing along $C\cap U$ is generated by $\pi$ and $C\cap U=\lbrace \pi=0\rbrace$.

Now, for any $f\in k[U]$, I can define a valuation $$\nu_C(f):=\textit{the  integer $k\geq 0$ s.t. $f\in (\pi^k)\setminus(\pi^{k+1})$}.$$ I would check that the valuation $\nu_C(f)$ does not depend from $U$. The author prooceds in this way.

[image]

I don't understand why the ideal of regular functions on $V$ vanishing along $C\cap V$ is generated by $\pi_{|V}$.

Any help?

Comment: Don't you mean "regular in codimension 1"?

Comment: @peterag yes my mistake. I've corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal of regular functions on $V$ vanishing along $C\cap V$ is a localization of the ideal of regular functions on $U$ vanishing along $C\cap U$. If a set generates an ideal, then it also generates any localization of that ideal: an arbitrary element in a localization of an ideal is just a fraction with numerator from the original ideal and denominator a unit, and so if you can generate the numerator, you have succeeded.

Comment: We have $V\subset U$, therefore $U\cap V\cap C=V\cap C$. However...What do you mean with "transport the relation back"? Can you expand the answer please?

Comment: I read too quickly and assumed that $V$ was another affine open. Revising...